# IIS SSL Settings - Require client certificates and self-signed certificates

Tags: ssl, iis-7, client-certificate

I am having a little challenge understanding digital certificates and ssl. In IIS SSL Settings for my website I am setting my website to **require client certificates**.

I am using a **self-signed certificate** for the site bindings, this is where I am unsure that this will work in conjunction with requiring client certificate for website.

While still in IIS, I click on the website and along the right margin there's a link to browse using SSL. The lock symbol shows up in the address bar but it still won't show the default page.

[image]

Comment: Did you actually install the certificate on the client?

Comment: I will presume you install the certificate on the server.  This error is normally caused by the client not trusting the certificate on the server.  Verify none of the things listed in "most likely reviews" is applicable.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates   Check this site, shows how to create self signed certifcate and apply it to the site forcing local user to communicate over a secure channel. Obviously this will only work internally and not public faving

Comment: I did install the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

If your have set **require client certificates** than the client which will access your site will have to have a client certificate which the web server has to trust to get a proper response. you could use [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) to create server and client certificates - a proper way would be to create a root certificate which would be used to create the server and client certificate. You could set client certificates to Ignore or Accept. The Required setting is only used if you want your web server to trust the client. For example, in an Active Directory Domain you have a publicly facing Web Server and you want that only users whom you have provided a client certificate have access. The same is used in some Online Banking Systems I know of where the client certificate is on a smart card and you are not able to access the OLB System without providing the certificate.